# PHP vs Python Handling of Unicode Values stored in DB

Tags: php, python, mysql, unicode

I've got a PHP-backed website that can handle data input from JSON.  The JSON inputs are stored in a DB and then later displayed to a user.  Regular stuff…

Now I'm trying to use a Python script to handle adding similar data and I'm running into Unicode issues.  Namely, special characters that Python inputs into the DB using `MySQLdb` don't come out right when the page is displayed (via PHP/HTML).

Here's an example:

- JSON Source: `© 2015`

  ---
- Data in DB from PHP insert: `Â© 2015`
- What it looks like on the web from PHP DB insert: `© 2015`

  ---
- Data in DB from Python insert `© 2015`
- What it looks like on the web from Python DB insert: `� 2015`

Generalized Code for `MySQLdb` (`comment` is `<type 'unicode'>` and where I'm having the trouble):

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "database",
    use_unicode=True, charset='utf8' )

dbc = db.cursor()

dbc.execute("INSERT INTO `marks` (`id`, `title`, `comment`) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s)",
    [ title, comment ])

db.commit()
db.close()
```

On the output side I'm using PHP [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to load and print the text as HTML:

```
@$descriptionText->loadHTML( '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'.$mark['Mark']['comment'] );
echo $descriptionText->saveHTML();
```

So, PHP is doing something that encodes the data in the DB so that it looks weird dumped out but renders correctly when encoded into HTML.  Is there any way I can duplicate this behavior in Python?

Comment: I tired as a test setting the db to not use unicode: `db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "database")` but it didn't seem to matter either way (still got `� 2015` output).

Comment: You are getting in deep.  Mojibake (`Â©`); `�` is another.  If you want further advice, start another thread, and include `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM .. WHERE ..` for examples of both cases.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames; that comment was old and I actually got things working after @metatoaster's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you haven't produced any code from your PHP backed website, we can't determine whether or not it is handling unicode correctly, or at all.  If the data in DB from PHP insert is indeed (as mentioned in question) presented as `Â© 2015` (specifically the python string `u'\xc2\xa9 2015'`, note the `u` denoting this as a unicode string) then what your PHP application actually did on insert is decode the input unicode string with the `utf-8` codec then on database insert everything is encoded as `ISO8859-1` (or `latin1`).  On loading, the query returns a `latin1` string which the PHP app decodes with the `utf8` codec to get back the original unicode.

For the Python code, since everything is done in `utf8` without the `latin1` step, when the PHP script tries to load that data, it will try and fail to decode as the byte `\xa9` is an error and PHP replace errors with the `\ufffd` unicode codepoint by default.

To make your Python insert compatible with your PHP website and as a test to see if this inference is correct, try

```
dbc.execute("INSERT INTO `marks` (`id`, `title`, `comment`)"
    "VALUES (NULL, %s, %s)", [
        title.encode('utf8').decode('latin1'),
        comment.encode('utf8').decode('latin1'),
])
```

This basically turn all the unicode into the raw latin1 codepoints that your PHP application expects, since as I mentioned it probably assumes all tables are `utf8` encoded strings as represented by the `latin1` charset.

Comment: Thank you!  `comment.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')` was all that was needed.  I wasn't sure how to better report the PHP code since I think the DB inserts are handled by a framework, but you were able to figure it out anyway. SO won't let me award the bounty yet but I will tomorrow.

Comment: After some more testing it was working with some unicode characters (like ©) but not others.  E.g. for a unicode input to Python of u'Wies\u0142aw' `encode('utf8').decode('latin1')` converts this to u'Wies\xc5\x82aw' and I  was getting `Wies�?aw` when viewing the page on the web.  The solution to this was to *disable* using unicode with the DB; basically `db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "database")` not `db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "database", use_unicode=True, charset='utf8' )`.

Comment: You may also want to investigate whether or not the tables are encoded using utf8 also by doing a `SHOW CREATE TABLE marks` and see if the `DEFAULT CHARSET` is `utf8`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`. I surmise this means it's really my PHP that's behaving badly?

Comment: Correct, most likely behaving in the way I described (assuming everything in the table is actual bytes and encodes that to utf8 before sending to client). The correct behavior is that the raw data as written to the DB by the programs (either PHP or Python) should be correctly utf8 encoded, but as you described, the PHP code isn't doing so, Python had to be modified to follow the wrong way to make things look right to end user.